# SSRS: Place a calculated row below another row

Tags: reporting-services

I can't insert a calculated line (CA) in a specific location between the lines of a category.
I have made a formula where the CA line sums the value of two lines of a category but I would like this line to be placed right after the two other lines from which it has taken the values.

[image]

The expression I used for the calculation is :

=SUM(VAL(IIF(Fields!U_Categorie.Value="Ventes de marchandises (en l'etat)" ,Fields!SoldeN.Value,0 )))
+SUM(VAL(IIF(Fields!U_Categorie.Value="Ventes de biens et services produits" ,Fields!SoldeN.Value,0 )))

[image]

I would like to add the sum of the two lines and place the new line just below the two lines. Because in this case it will appear at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would almost certainly do this in the dataset query. Append the additional rows to your dataset and add (if required) some ordering logic (a sort order column) to the dataset too. If the CA row needs to be excluded from other calculations you would have to handle that separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired output to create calculated field and use that field in row group.

I Have created sample report, try this below steps and screenshot in your report.

1. Create Calculated field CA
2. Add CA as row group
3. Set row visibility using expression.

[image: Create Calculated field]

[image: Add row group]

[image: Set row visibility]

[image: Sample Output]